# User's name isn't showing up in the header after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I want the users's name to appear instead of Login in the NavDropDown but it's not showing up.. It works only when a new user is registered but when I login again it doesn't work. I have no idea what I've missed here, I still receive userInfo in my state so I got no clue why this not working

header.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, NavDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import { logout } from "../actions/UserActions";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

function Header() {
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" className="navCustom">
        <Container>
          <LinkContainer to="/">
            <Navbar.Brand>eCommerce</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
            <Nav
              className="ms-auto my-2 my-lg-0"
              // style={{ maxHeight: "100px" }}
              navbarScroll
            >
              <LinkContainer to="/">
                <Nav.Link>
                  <i className="fas fa-home"></i> Home
                </Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/cart">
                <Nav.Link>
                  <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart
                </Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              {userInfo ? (
                <NavDropdown title={userInfo.name} id="username">
                  <LinkContainer to="/profile">
                    <NavDropdown.Item>Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
                  </LinkContainer>

                  <NavDropdown.Item onClick={logoutHandler}>
                    Logout
                  </NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
              ) : (
                <LinkContainer to="/login">
                  <Nav.Link>
                    <i className="fas fa-user"></i> Login
                  </Nav.Link>
                </LinkContainer>
              )}
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

store.js:

```
import {
  legacy_createStore as createStore,
  combineReducers,
  applyMiddleware,
} from "redux";
//import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {
  productListReducers,
  productDetailsReducers,
} from "./reducers/ProductReducers";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/CartReducers";
import { userLoginReducers } from "./reducers/UserReducers";
import { userRegisterReducers } from "./reducers/UserReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducers,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducers,
  cart: cartReducer,
  userLogin: userLoginReducers,
  userRegister: userRegisterReducers,
});

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
  : [];

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
  : null;

const initialState = {
  cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage },
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
};
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

userReducers.js:

```
import {
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
  USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,
  USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
  USER_LOGOUT,
} from "../constants/UserConstants";

export const userLoginReducers = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { laoding: true };
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { laoding: false, userInfo: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { laoding: false, error: action.payload };

    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return {};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const userRegisterReducers = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_REGISTER_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload };
    case USER_REGISTER_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return {};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting another object with userInfo in it on your login. Try replacing

```
case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload };
```

with

```
case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, ...action.payload };
```

I think it would solve your problem.

Comment: That didn't work, I did the same thing with the login case as well and didn't work. In your solution after register it doesn't redirect but user gets registered. Shouldn't be something with the login case, because that's where the problem is @sepand-y

Comment: @khaled yeah that was my mistake it had to be done only in login.

Comment: But that still didn't work though @sepand-y